# BASH: Edit a JSON file

Tags: json, bash, awk

I need help in writing a script to edit a file.json.  Below is the JSON file:

```
{
    "version" : "1.0",
    "analytics" : {
        "rsids" : "",
        "charset" : "UTF-8",
        "ssl" : false,
        "offlineEnabled" : true,
        "lifecycleTimeout" : 300,
        "privacyDefault" : "optedin",
        "poi" : []
    },
    "target" : {
        "clientCode" : "",
        "timeout" : 5
    },
    "audienceManager" : {
        "server" : ""
    }
}
```

I need to edit the above file.json and provide values for rsids, client code, and server.

Comment: http://xmodulo.com/2013/05/how-to-parse-json-string-via-command-line-on-linux.html

Comment: Use [`sed`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sed.1.html)?

Comment: Yes. please.  @Wrikken -- your link I believe shows how to parse a JSON.  Here I need to edit it.

Comment: _"Using jq, you can parse, filter, map, and **transform** JSON-structured data effortlessly."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Gnu Awk version 4, you could use `patsplit()`. Try the following bash script:

```
#! /bin/bash

IFS=$'\n' ar=( rsids="1 2" clientCode="2" server="3")
mv file.json file.json.bak
gawk -va="${ar[*]}" -f a.awk file.json.bak > file.json
```

where `a.awk` is:

```
BEGIN {
    n=split(a,b,"\n")
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        split(b[i],z,"=")
        w[("\""z[1]"\"")]=("\""z[2]"\"")
    }
    RS="^$" #Read whole file in a single record
}
{
    n=patsplit($0,c,/"[^"]*"[[:blank:]]*:[[:blank:]]*"[^"]*"/,s1)
    printf "%s", s1[0]
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        patsplit(c[i],d,/"[^"]*"/,s2)
        if (d[1] in w)
            d[2]=w[d[1]]
        printf "%s%s%s%s%s%s",s2[0],d[1],s2[1],d[2],s2[2],s1[i]
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{
    "version" : "1.0",
    "analytics" : {
        "rsids" : "1 2",
        "charset" : "UTF-8",
        "ssl" : false,
        "offlineEnabled" : true,
        "lifecycleTimeout" : 300,
        "privacyDefault" : "optedin",
        "poi" : []
    },
    "target" : {
        "clientCode" : "2",
        "timeout" : 5
    },
    "audienceManager" : {
        "server" : "3"
    }
}
```

**Edit**

If you like to call with command line args, change first line of script to:

```
IFS=$'\n' ar=( "$@" )
```

and call it like:

```
bash$ editJson rsids="1 2" clientCode="2" server="3"
```

Comment: Thank you.  Is there a way to pass the values for rsids, clietCode, and server, through the command line when calling the script?

Answer (score 1):

If you have Ruby

```
require "rubygems"
require 'json'
parsed = JSON.parse( File.open("file.json").read )
puts parsed["analytics"]["rsids"]
puts parsed["target"]["clientCode"]
```

Comment: This will not edit the file `file.json`. It prints fields, but it do not insert new values for the fields back into the file..